# Lines Beside Text - HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css, lines

What I want:

[image]

Current Code

```
<div class="grid3"><h1 class="lines">Welcome!</h1> <p class="lines2">Text</p></div>

.lines { color: #d5a72b; padding-right: 4px; float: left;}
.lines2 { text-indent: -999999px; background: url('../images/line.png') repeat-x; }
```

What I get:
[image]

Comment: I'm feeling as if you are not Googling anything. You've posted for help like 5 times without researching anything. Don't become a help hogger, or you will end up like me, banned from asking.

Comment: How does that code give you that outcome? Where's your CSS?

Comment: Aha I do try and google, trust me, I have had like 23 things to post as questions, but I am only posting shit I cannot find myself on google, although the last question was a bit stupid, and its only been 3, but anyways, thanks for the advice, I will try and google harder. This is my first real attempt at coding, so I want to do it right, instead of giving up half way through, :P

Comment: Learn the difference between block vs. inline elements, as well as floats. Heading tags and DIVs are block by default, but you can change that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
<h1><span>Heading</span></h1>

h1 {
    background-image: url("lines.png") left middle repeat-x; }
h1 span {
    background: #bgcolor;
    padding: 1em; }
```

It's a hack, but I don't believe even CSS3 currently has a solution for this problem except possibly `border-image`, however that still isn't supported by IE10.

Comment: I tried using the :after but I have no idea how I could do it, would I do line:after { image: url(); } or { background-image: url(); } not sure... Let me look at a few sites that have something like it and see how they did it,